# How can I envelope distort a circle into a polygon?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I have square layer, containing a circular image surrounded by white, and I need to envelope distort *just the circle* into a polygon shape. When I do **Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object**, however, the whole square shape of the image -- including the white "corners" -- is included in the distort.

**Before and after (actual result):**

[image: Before and after (actual result)]

How can I specify that I only want a circular portion of an image layer to be distorted to the edges of the polygon?

**Before and after (desired result):**

[image: Before and after (desired result)]

Comment: is your shape a compound shape? can you post a screen-shot of your layers?

Comment: The top object shape? No, it's just a single path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always distorts the (square) bounding box, rather than the underlying shape (circle).

For precision envelope distorts of non-rectangular shapes - which are almost always a lot more complex in reality than it seems they "should" be when you imagine them - it's usually best to use a **mesh** then sculpt them into shape by hand by pulling parts of the mesh around:

[image]

Tip for symmetrical editing of mesh corners: grab opposite corners all at once, hit `s` to switch to the Scale tool, hold shift and drag to pull or push them all the same distance from the centre.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still incredulous that tediously pushing pixels around till you get close to the shape you want is the only way this can be done; it seems like it ought to be *trivial* for a computer to do programmatically, and such a common task that someone ought to have written the software to do it. But oh well.

Comment: @Jay its only trivial if thats how the gui was implemented. There is millions of trivial things that become nontrivial because of Adobe policy.